# Remove two characters/letters before a special character "|" occurring in the string in Python (or using regex)

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a string:

> TCTAY**NC**|078/A - TIHGKH**KH**|078/A - SOCGKH**KH**|078/A - PDENB**UA**|078/A - MTLKA**ZN**|078/B - TYLZN

and I would like to remove two letters (highlighted in bold above) before every occurrence of the pipe symbol `|` so the output string looks like this:

> TCTAY|078/A - TIHGKH|078/A - SOCGKH|078/A - PDENB|078/A - MTLKA|078/B - TYLZN

What is the best way to do this in Python with or without a RegEx? I tried this and got a completely wrong output than expected.

```py
import re

output_str = re.sub (r'T.*?|', '|', input_str)
```

Comment: `|` is a special regex metacharacter defining an alternation. You need to escape it, ``\|``. And if you care to match just letters, why use `.*?`? Use `[A-Z]{2}`. Not sure why you used `T` at all. `[A-Z]{2}\|` seems to fit your requirements.